# Connecting to Azure SQL using Service Principal in NodeJS, but token is rejected

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-service-principal

I am having trouble getting my NodeJS application to connect to an Azure SQL Database using the Service Principal. However, when I try to do the same thing with a C# Snippet, it works fine. What I have noticed is that the tokens returned by the auth on both languages is a bit different, and if I take the correct token from C# and hard code it into NodeJS, my SQL Connection now succeeds.

I am first using ms-rest-azure to perform my authentication, and providing my clientId, tenantId and clientSecret. This returns back a valid credential, from which I am extracting the accessToken.

Then, I am using tedious to try to connect to the Azure SQL at *.database.windows.net and providing the accessToken value in the configuration.

I just get **Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'**

What am I doing wrong in the ms-rest-azure login to give me a token that is rejected by Azure SQL? One thing I saw is that the working token has an audience of *database.windows.net*, where-as the one from ms-rest-azure is *management.core.windows.net*.

I've been stuck for a few days, if anybody has any clues here that would be awesome. The documentation on ms-rest-azure seems pretty non-existent and just gives you the runaround to Azure Sales pages.

```
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
const { reject } = require('async');


let clientSecret = "xxx";
let serverName = "xxx.database.windows.net";
let databaseName = "xxx";
let clientId = "xxx";
let tenantId = "xxx";

azureCredentials = msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId, function(err, credentials) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    credentials.getToken((err, results) => {
        if(err) return reject(err);
        
        let accessToken = results.accessToken;

        var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
        var Request = require('tedious').Request;

        var config = {
            server: serverName,
            authentication: {
                type: 'azure-active-directory-access-token',
                options: {
                    token: accessToken
                }
            }
            ,options: {
                debug: {
                packet: true,
                data: true,
                payload: true,
                token: false,
                log: true
                },
                database: databaseName,
                encrypt: true
            }  
        };

        var connection = new Connection(config);

        connection.connect();

        connection.on('connect', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            executeStatement();
        }
        );

        connection.on('debug', function(text) {
            console.log(text);
        }
        );

        function executeStatement() {
        request = new Request("select * from Text", function(err, rowCount) {
            if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            } else {
            console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
            }

            connection.close();
        });

        request.on('row', function(columns) {
            columns.forEach(function(column) {
            if (column.value === null) {
                console.log('NULL');
            } else {
                console.log(column.value);
            }
            });
        });

        request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {
            console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
        });

        connection.execSql(request);
        }
    });   
})
```

Comment: COuld you please analyze your token via https://jwt.ms?

Answer (score 3):

when we use the certificates in the package `ms-rest-azure` to get token, In default, the token's audience is `https://management.core.windows.net/`, it just can be used to call Azure rest api. If we want to use Azure AD token to connect sql, the token's audience should be be `https://database.windows.net/`. So we should update the code used to get token as

```
msrestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(
    clientId,
    clientSecret,
    tenantId,
    {
      tokenAudience: "https://database.windows.net/",
    },
```

For example

1. Create A service principal

```
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n 'MyApp' --skip-assignment
```

2. Configure SQL Database

a. [Use your Azure Sql AD admin to connect Azure SQL vai SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell)

b. Add the service principal to the database you need use

```
create user [<Azure_AD_principal_name>] from external provider
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [<Azure_AD_principal_name>]
```

3. code

```
var msrestAzure = require("ms-rest-azure");
var { Connection, Request } = require("tedious");

let clientSecret = "xxx";
let serverName = "xxx.database.windows.net";
let databaseName = "xxx";
let clientId = "xxx";
let tenantId = "xxx";

async function getConnect() {
  // way for Azure Service Principal
  let databaseCredentials = await msrestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(
    clientId,
    clientSecret,
    tenantId,
    {
      tokenAudience: "https://database.windows.net/",
    },
  );

  // getting access token
  let databaseAccessToken = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    databaseCredentials.getToken((err, results) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(results.accessToken);
    });
  });
  var config = {
    server: serverName,
    authentication: {
      type: "azure-active-directory-access-token",
      options: {
        token: databaseAccessToken,
      },
    },
    options: {
      debug: {
        packet: true,
        data: true,
        payload: true,
        token: false,
        log: true,
      },
      database: databaseName,
      encrypt: true,
    },
  };

  var connection = new Connection(config);
  connection.connect();
  connection.on("connect", function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    executeStatement(connection);
  });

  connection.on("debug", function (text) {
    console.log(text);
  });
}
function executeStatement(connection) {
  request = new Request("select * from CSVTest", function (err, rowCount) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(rowCount + " rows");
    }

    connection.close();
  });

  request.on("row", function (columns) {
    columns.forEach(function (column) {
      if (column.value === null) {
        console.log("NULL");
      } else {
        console.log(column.value);
      }
    });
  });

  request.on("done", function (rowCount, more) {
    console.log(rowCount + " rows returned");
  });

  connection.execSql(request);
}

getConnect()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("run successfully");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/pull/863)

Comment: I copy your code and follow your instruction but I encounter issue: "Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'." Can you help me on this matter

Comment: @Noyti Could you please tell me how you configure Azure SQL server AD admin and create Databse user?